# Сохранение объекта BufferedImage в графический файл

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. Хочу реализовать функцию сохранения графики, рисующейся в компонент JFrame - Canvas. Для этого параллельно к рисовке в Canvas рисую в объект Graphics2D объекта BufferedImage. 
При передаче в файловый поток и сохранении операция производитс успешная, на выходе получаем файл графического формата, но ПРОБЛЕМА: изображение черно-белое.
Какие нюансы взаимодействия всех этих объектов я не учел?
Ниже код:

```
//Объявляем объект BufferedImage
BufferedImage imgResult;
imgResult = new BufferedImage(pCanvik.getWidth(), pCanvik.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

//Участок кода, рисующий в объект BufferedImage

imgResult.getGraphics().setColor(Color.red);
imgResult.getGraphics().drawOval(b.getOvalPivot().x, b.getOvalPivot().y, b.getRadius()*2, b.getRadius()*2);

// Ну а здесь завершающий этап - сохранение в файл

try 
{                               
ImageIO.write(imgResult, "png", new File("image.bmp"));
System.out.println("Success!");
}

catch (IOException e) 
{
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю это потому, что вы создаёте два контекста рисования, выставляете цвет в один, а рисуете в другой. Создайте нормальный контекст, используйте его, а в конце уничтожьте его как положено (это важно, потому что для рисования в буффер выделяются системные ресурсы и даже аппаратные и их желательно корректно освободить, иначе они будут освобождены не сразу).

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(pCanvik.getWidth(), pCanvik.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics g = image.getGraphics();

// рисуем на g

g.dispose();

// сохраняем
```

Comment: Да. Спасибо. Объявив глобальную переменную графического контекста и связав её с объектом BufferedImage, я решил свою проблему, это действительно помогло.